# Could I enter Canada with more alcohol than the tax-free limit and pay at the arrival?

Tags: canada, alcohol, import-taxes

I am going to Canada and I would like to bring some specific local alcohol that is apparently not sold in Canada (at least not at the LCBO I would go to). I would like to bring enough for a party of a friend.

I know the limit on tax-free import of alcohol is about 1L, but I wish to bring in a case (6 75cL bottles). Could I just come with my bottles and declare them at the customs when I arrive, or should I prepare some paper in advance (I am especially wondering if there is a limit an individual can bring in without it being considered commercial import)? Also, is there a way to determine in advance the estimated amount of taxes?

Note that I will travel with the bottles (no shipping), in case that matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just bring the receipt from the store and tell customs you have over-limit alcohol. A half-case won't be considered commercial.

Duty is rather complicated and depends on the exact type of liquor and the alcohol content. Printing off the maker's webpage may help. As a very rough metric expect to pay about 20% tax.